# Android Application with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, variables, textview

Hi How can I show the variable on the TextView screen.

```
var a=(labelProbArray[0][0])
```

I want to show variable a in TextView.

Thanks...

You can also help with its display with the button.

Comment: you can simply show it in textview  `textview.text = a`

Answer (score 0):

You can play with textview by simply declaring an instance of it in your activity file.

**Try this -**

```
    private lateinit var textView:TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    textView = findViewById(R.id.text2)
    var a=(labelProbArray[0][0])
    textView.text= a

    }
```